# Is it possible to set an android icon from a drawable in a separate jar?

Tags: android

I want to set a menu option icon for a drawable that is in another jar inside an xml file.

```
<item android:id="@+id/my_location"
      android:title="My Location"
      android:icon="@+drawable/my_location">
```

Instead of drawable/my_location have something like com.somelib.R.drawable.someDrawable.

I can set this in onCreateOptionsMenu but was just wondering if it could be done via the xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to set a menu option icon for a
>   drawable that is in another jar inside
>   an xml file.

Drawable *resources* cannot go in JARs. You are welcome to store images in a JAR and deal with them outside of the resource framework.

> I can set this in onCreateOptionsMenu
>   but was just wondering if it could be
>   done via the xml file.

No, because, again, images in a JAR file are not resources, defined as images in `res/drawable-*/` in your project. Sorry!